# No ip address in oracle linux in virtual box with bridged adapter over WiFi

Tags: virtualbox, putty, oracle-linux

I am trying to connect through putty to my oracle linux installation in virtual box and I set Bridged Adapter as the Network Adapter. But I cannot get an ip to be connected from Putty. I am trying this by using my office's WiFi connection.
Could there be any reason and a work-around for this error.
Thanks.
Following is the ifconfig output.

```
[sandun@localhost ~]$ ifconfig
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::e52c:9da9:ad4c:d17a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 08:00:27:92:d9:bb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1  bytes 60 (60.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 38  bytes 6660 (6.5 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 48  bytes 4272 (4.1 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 48  bytes 4272 (4.1 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
    ether 52:54:00:d0:1c:f7  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

[sandun@localhost ~]$
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping from host to guest ipaddress 192.168.122.1(assuming this ipadress is static otherwise run the command ifconfig virbr0 to get correct ipaddress).If ping is successful use that ip address for putty.If ping timed out or unable to reach host try to disable firewall or add bridged network to trusted interface(on guest vm).